# How do I get the good ending in Metro: Exodus?

Tags: metro-exodus

I don't know what happened while I was playing but got a bad ending. I found

> Arthyon in hell

Can any body tell me why did I get bad ending? How can I get a good ending? Is there any logic behind the story line that put us to any bad or good one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [This GameRant article](https://gamerant.com/metro-exodus-how-to-get-good-ending/) by *Dalton Cooper*:

> To get the Good ending in Metro Exodus, players just need to be a “good” person. This means knocking out enemies instead of killing them whenever possible. It also means going out of the way to help any people in need. For example, players are more likely to unlock the “Good” ending if they complete the various side quests that they encounter during their journey.

To get the bad just go opposite

Answer (score 1):

To have a good ending at least two of your crewmates need to decide to follow your journey. There are 3 crew members who need to decide, they are:

> Duke on the Volga level, he may decide to kill the priest and gets wounded in the following firefight which prevents him from jumping on the Aurora.
>  Damir on the Caspian level may decide to stay and fight for his people.
>  Alyosha on the Taiga level, he will get wounded and confined to a wheelchair.

If not at least two of them follow you then

> there will be not enough blood donors in the end to save you, so you die.

To make them stay with the crew you need to acquire moral points during the playthrough, these are usually optional tasks explained by NPCs. You can find the full list of moral points in the [Metro Wiki](https://metrovideogame.fandom.com/wiki/Moral_Points#List_of_Moral_Points_in_Metro:_Exodus).